# iPhone Text View within a Flip View

Tags: iphone, keyboard, view, uitextview, flip

I have a Flip View and on this "flipped" view I have a UItextView, (NOT a textField).

I need to be able to display a rightBarButtonItem when the editing of the textView begins and then to click this rightBarButtonItem to resign the keyboard.

There are lots of similar problems such as this but none of them are on a flip view.

I really appreciate the help. This has been driving me crazy.

Thanks,

Stefan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the [UITextViewDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html) in your view controller and implement either the `textViewDidBeginEditing:` method, or the `textViewDidChange:` method.

Comment: Hi,

I had tried this but it didn't work. Since then I have decided that flip view is too much hassle so I have gone back to the simple push view controller.

Thanks for the suggestion.